# SQL Server 2014 Database vs. Schema Permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions

Two Schemas:
 dbo
 test

I'd like to grant create table to the test schema for a windows group; but not have them be able to create a table in the dbo schema.

I have tried:

```
GRANT CONTROL, ALTER ON SCHEMA :: test TO [ad\windows_group];

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO [ad\windows_group];

DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA :: DBO TO [ad\windows_group];

GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA :: DBO TO [ad\windows_group]
```

The members of the windows_group can still create a table on the dbo schema; but cannot drop it.

I've seen multiple references saying that DENYing the ALTER schema permission should block the creation of the table; but I think I'm missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to grant create table to the test schema for a windows group;
>   but not have them be able to create a table in the dbo schema.

The correct grants are:

```
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::test TO [ad\windows_group];

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO [ad\windows_group];
```

> but not have them be able to create a table in the dbo schema.

They would not be able to do that without ALTER permissions on dbo.

> I think I'm missing something.

Somehow you've granted that user ALTER on the dbo schema or the database.